# lvalue and function result -- dependency?

Tags: c, types, lvalue

Consider the following snippet:

```
int func(char *ptr);
...
n += func(p + n);
```

Does this code yield undefined behaviour, since the function's argument depends on lvalue? I'd assume that a compiler would calculate a result of function, and then increment `p + n`, or this probably is compiler specific?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Add a reference and that's an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a sequence point before a function enter in function call. It means that every value computation and the side effects associated with an argument are completed before function entered in a function call.

C11-§6.5.2.2/10:

> There is a sequence point after the evaluations of the function designator and the actual arguments but before the actual call.

So, in case of

```
n += func(p + n);
```

`p + n` will be calculated before the function call.

Comment: It seems that the statement *"all the side effects on arguments are completed before function entered"* is misleading. How does it apply here? What is the side effect here? The increment of `n`? But it is not happening before the call. `p+n` is evaluated with the *previous* value of `n`

Comment: @EugeneSh.; Actually it seems question lack some information. In this case value computation of `p+n`. OP says: *I'd assume that a compiler would calculate a result of function, and then increment `p + n`*. But, opposite is true. `p+n` will be calculated first and then function will return its result.

Comment: @EugeneSh.; No. Standard says: *The presence of a sequence point
between the evaluation of expressions A and B implies that **every value computation and
side effect** associated with A is sequenced before every value computation and side effect
associated with B.* Its not only about side effect but also abot value computations. In this case I am talking about value computation of `p+n` as there is no side effect associated with the argument.

Comment: So I think it has actually little to do with sequence points. It's just a regular read-evaluate-store computation.

Comment: @EugeneSh.; Yes. Nothing to worry about. I think OP just overthink on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
n += func(p + n);
```

is well defined since `n` is accessed for writing only after the function call is completed. The function call can be completed only after reading the value of `n`.

Comment: How can it be explained in terms of sequence points, if they are relevant here at all? Seems like they are not. there is no side effects here.

Comment: @EugeneSh., Even though a function call involves a sequence point, that applies only to the evaluation of its arguments, I don't think it is relevant to deciding whether `n += func(p+n);` is well defined.